# how to use ipinfodb API in php

Tags: php

I m using the following code to use "ipinfodb.com  API". This was written on that website. I have used correct key

and a 'REMOTE_ADDR' but  it gives me following result :

---

**Result :**

```
Warning: include(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in C:\xampp

\htdocs\temp\index.php on line 18

Warning: include(http://api.ipinfodb.com/ip2locationlite.class.php): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper 

could be found in C:\xampp\htdocs\temp\index.php on line 18

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'http://api.ipinfodb.com/ip2locationlite.class.php' for inclusion 

(include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\temp\index.php on line 18

Fatal error: Class 'ip2location_lite' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\temp\index.php on line 21
```

---

code used is  ::::

```
<?php
  include('ip2locationlite.class.php');

  //Load the class
  $ipLite = new ip2location_lite;
  $ipLite->setKey('<your_api_key>');

  //Get errors and locations
  $locations = $ipLite->getCity($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
  $errors = $ipLite->getError();

  //Getting the result
  echo "<p>\n";
  echo "<strong>First result</strong><br />\n";
  if (!empty($locations) && is_array($locations)) {
  foreach ($locations as $field => $val) {
    echo $field . ' : ' . $val . "<br />\n";
   }
 }
  echo "</p>\n";

  //Show errors
  echo "<p>\n";
  echo "<strong>Dump of all errors</strong><br />\n";
  if (!empty($errors) && is_array($errors)) {
  foreach ($errors as $error) {
    echo var_dump($error) . "<br /><br />\n";
  }
 } else {
   echo "No errors" . "<br />\n";
  }
  echo "</p>\n";
 ?>
```

---

Help me as soon as possible.

Comment: code is as follows :<?php
include('ip2locationlite.class.php');
 
//Load the class
$ipLite = new ip2location_lite;
$ipLite->setKey('<your_api_key>');
 
//Get errors and locations
$locations = $ipLite->getCity($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$errors = $ipLite->getError();
 
//Getting the result
echo "<p>\n";
echo "<strong>First result</strong><br />\n";
if (!empty($locations) && is_array($locations)) {
  foreach ($locations as $field => $val) {
    echo $field . ' : ' . $val . "<br />\n";
  }
}
echo "</p>\n";

Comment: //Show errors
echo "<p>\n";
echo "<strong>Dump of all errors</strong><br />\n";
if (!empty($errors) && is_array($errors)) {
  foreach ($errors as $error) {
    echo var_dump($error) . "<br /><br />\n";
  }
} else {
  echo "No errors" . "<br />\n";
}
echo "</p>\n";
?>

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to open a php file over http with something like

```
include 'http://somesite.com/somefile.php';
```

Your version of php is preventing this with security configuration in php.ini. Either change these settings or download the code and install it locally on the server.

The later is a better idea, since these security settings are in place for good reason. Just look [in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) for further explanation.